# is there any method avalable to clear all my android app task(Activity Back stack) below 21?

Tags: android

## ***This question seems to be duplicate but it is not!***

I want to close my whole application in one shot.

Note: My application may have multiple **Activity Back Stack**

For API level >=21 bellow code working fine

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (activityManager != null) 
{
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
     {
         for (ActivityManager.AppTask appTask : activityManager.getAppTasks()) 
         {
                appTask.finishAndRemoveTask();
         }
     }
}
```

**I need code for below 21**

> I have tried the following solution listed bellow

1. **finishAffinity()** - [Official Doc First First Line](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finishAffinity())-> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the **current task** that have the same affinity, means it will clear current task not all the task
2. **finishAndRemoveTask ()** - [Official Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finishAndRemoveTask()) -> not available below 21
3. **System.exit(0)** - not working
4. **android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())** - not working

Comment: check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052849/how-to-close-all-activities-in-android-and-close-from-task-manager

Comment: @vahab-balouchzahi I don't want to use that! I want some authentic way see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/11035328/3019165